# 3-Coloring Problem Question

Tags: algorithms, 3-sat, colorings

So I understand that finding a solution to the 3-coloring problem takes exponential time.  However, say you had a friend who you could give a graph G to and he can say in constant time whether it is 3-colorable or not.  Is it possible to find a 3-coloring of G in polynomial time with his help? I think it might be possible but I'm not sure if my approach is correct.

Say the 3 colors are RGB.  You assign some vertex R and give G back to your friend.  If he says Yes, then keep it colored R, if No then leave it be.  Go through every vertex this way assigning R, and then with G and B afterwards.  The graph will be 3-colored at the end, but this would only take O(V*3) time.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is not known that 3-coloring takes exponential time. Even if P is different from NP, it could still be the case that 3-coloring can be solved in subexponential time, though the Exponential Time Hypothesis (ETH) precludes this possibility (if you assume the hypothesis).

Second, regarding your suggested solution. The black box only accepts graphs, it doesn't accept partially colored graphs. You need to give a reduction which only feeds the black box  actual graphs.

Third, if a graph is 3-colorable, then there is always a 3-coloring in which a particular vertex is red. So what you're really trying to do is ask whether there is a 3-coloring in which a given set of vertices has the same color, another set of the vertices has a different color, and yet another one has the remaining color. See if you can somehow encode some of these constraints using graphs rather than partial colorings.

Comment: How would I go about encoding those constraints using graphs? Do you mean to create 3 separate graphs, one for each color? I don't see how that would work.

Comment: It's your homework question, not mine...

Comment: See also the answer David Richerby links to – it uses basically your construction rather than my idea.